# Best Practice to Host a Web Server on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssl, nginx, raspberry-pi3, web-hosting

Apologises in advance for such a question.

I have looked around for some time but still have no clarity.

I have the Raspberry Pi.  I use nginx to host my web server.
I have created a local ssl using openssl so that browsers can view it without complaint.  But I read that you should not use local.cert for a production server. if i do not use a domain name for my server i cannot pay for a genuine ssl certificate.

So what are my options?

I suggest that in the near future all web server will require genuine ssl certifcation.

Any suggestions i will be very grateful for. i will also post back anything i discover myself.

Thanks!

Comment: "i cannot pay for a genuine ssl certificate." There are free genuine certificates. See Let's Encrypt for one example.  "I suggest that in the near future all web server will require genuine ssl certifcation." This is already an ongoing trend. HTTP is labeled as unsecure in browsers or will be soon, HTTPS is forced by HSTS including preloading of TLDs (ex: Google TLDs such as `.DEV`), etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Hi, thanks for ur comment, Yes, i am going by I need to use SSL to avoid techincal debt. The point about paying for a SSL was in reference that I would need to provide a genine domain name when creating the certifcate. to use localhost is frowned upon and I agree it would negate the point of using  ssl.  So this means i cannot host a web server on th e Rpi unless I attribute a domain to it you see

Comment: Some domains are available for a few dollars. Which is less that what you will pay yearly for electricity to host your webserver. Register any domain name, and use it as suffix for all your naming. As for localhost, see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek use that may be an option. But I am wanting to resell this product so I would have to create a new domain name for each user...